# How to capture https traffic?

Tags: windows, https, capture

I want to know if any tool captures https traffic. I spend many hours searching on Google but did not find an answer. I need to analyze some packets from my application.

How can I capture this https traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn´t specify the platform or the nature of your application. Just giving it a try, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a HTTP Proxy capable of capturing HTTPS requests.

Comment: My app is .NET application. I have used Fiddler but i can't find any option for https protocol. Do you have any article about it. Thank for your reply.

Comment: Check http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/90_Developer_Tools/020_Fiddler#Configuring_Fiddler_to_Capture_HTTPS_Traffic

Comment: I work by your tutorial and not success. Can't capture my package from my app. And when i try to type https://mysites.com, it's not also capture anythings.

Comment: Can you capture regular HTTP traffic?

Comment: Yes if it's http traffic, i can capture by Wireshark or Fiddler.

Comment: I think you should open a new question if you´re having problems using fiddler. For to start with, what happens if you´re running fiddler and open up the https site?

Answer (score 1):

Capturing HTTPS traffic is one of [Ettercap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap_%28computing%29)'s claims to fame.

Comment: Ettercap is a suite for man in the middle attacks on LAN, but i want to see my packages from my app to my server. Thank for your reply.

Comment: I'm only use web hosting with PHP script, so i can't run any things on server except PHP script. Thank @sarnold.

Comment: Ah; then you're in a very tight spot. I can't think of any mechanisms that would let you accomplish what you want to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

which operating system are you running? For Linux, Wireshark is a very famous packet sniffing tool.

Comment: Do you have tutorial about sniffing on Wireshark ? I'm running my app on Windows.

Comment: I know this. I mean is how to watch package information https as http package on Wireshark. Thank MBober. :)

Comment: You can also try Mozilla Firefox/IE plugin [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) to accomplish this. captures all the http and https traffic for requests starting from Firefox/IE.